# Questions about extending any Django app

Tags: django, django-forms, pinax

My old worker installed Pinax through PIP and it's installed in site-packages. All the apps lives there. Our own apps are within our Django project structure.

I want to modify Pinax's account app, by switching the `create_user`'s `is_active` flag to False. Currently, the app makes it `True`. I also want to add additional functionality to `create_user` or whatever function I want to do.

```
from pinax.account import forms
class MyCustomizeForm(forms.SignupForm):
   def create_user(....):
      super(....)
      // additional...
```

Maybe this?
But doesn't that require me to do at least two commit transactions talking to DB?

Is that preferable? Also, does doing this require me to change anything else in my Django project (how users signup, what views it uses... what forms it uses)?

Currently, I've an app living in my Django project supposes to deal with the extension / customization of `account` app. I can't commit site-packages to VCS.... I mean.. I am not supposed to make any changes there.

Thanks.

---

Pinax account/models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    def its_own_method(...)
# this is in the same indentation level as class Account

def create_account(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    if instance is None:
        return
    account, created = Account.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_account, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#signals) for exactly this situation. Signals are meant for apps that need to be distributed generally and won't always know how they will be integrated into a project.

The signal of interest to you here is the [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#pre-save). You can connect a pre_save to the pinax.account model and be notified when a save is about to happen. This will give you a chance to make changes to that model instance. Signals are synchronous, meaning you are making your change serially, right before the pinax.accounts will finish committing the save

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying the custom actions will be performed before `save()` actually gets called, or before it's finished till the last line?

Comment: The pre_save signal will deliver you the model instance that is about to be saved. You have a chance to modify it in the context of that signal handler. You wouldn't need to call save on it in that handler. It is about to be saved and will be once it finishes all of the pre_save signals.

Comment: Thanks. But doing `pre_save.connect(make_inactive, sender=User)` would mean whenever `User` model is doing save, it will trigger `make_inactive` function. I updated my post, with Pinax account's signal. What should I do instead?

Comment: @User007: if the instance is new, it won't have a value for `pk`, yet. So just only mess with `is_active` if `instance.pk is None`.

Comment: Yea exactly. It will get called for every save if you are using the pre_save signal so you would just take Chris's suggestion and check for what you need. Only modify it if it is new.

Comment: @jdi and Chris, thanks. I've gotten that part working. But I don't think signals will work for me without modifying the origianl app code if I want to add user to, say, LDAP, apart from Django's its own db, because my configuration requires me to pass in the raw password. But pre- or post-save will not allow me to send the raw password around, unless I inserted `send(...)` signal inside the original Pinax code, passing that raw password. Is that the case? What can you suggest me to look at? Thanks.

Comment: Thats somewhat of a different topic altogether. Integrating LDAP requires adding a custom authentication backend and some other considerations. Read: http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#user-objects

Comment: Thanks. I will check this off. I've already integrated with LDAP_AUTH. I will make a new thread instead.